# How to set FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES to false using spring xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, javabeans

I am trying to deserialize a json response I am receiving in to an object. I am getting the following error:

`org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "initialized"`

I know where this `initialized` field is coming from but I can't edit the object class at the moment. Rather I'd want to turn off this exception being thrown when it encounters a field not present in the class by editing the object mapper: `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)`

I am using `RestTemplate` to call the url. The restTemplate instance I am using is a bean hence a singleton and this is being created in an xml file like this:

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate"
      p:interceptors-ref="rest-template-client-interceptors"/>
```

The problem is that I'm not sure how to set DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES to false by the construction of the RestTemplate via xml. I am new to spring so not sure where to start.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You must configure RestTemplate message converter (MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter) to use a custom object mapper.

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">

    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper" ref="customObjectMapper"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>    
<bean id="customObjectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="customObjectMapper" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="configure" />
    <property name="arguments"> 
        <list>
            <value type="org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.Feature">FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES</value>
            <value>false</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```